# Buttons work only on the second click on custom popup c#

Tags: c#, winforms, onclick, popup

when i move between forms buttons works as expected, but when im closing my custom pop up only seconds click on any button will trigger it

this is the code im using to load my custom popup

```
public void loadPopUp(Form from, Form to)
{
    to.Tag = from;
    to.Show(from);
}
```

and this is the code my using to close my custom popup

```
public void closePopUp(string formName)
{
    for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        string name = Application.OpenForms[i].Name; //for debugging only
        if (Application.OpenForms[i].Name == formName)
            Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
    }           
}
```

note: this is not asp.net application

Comment: From which event handler do you call that _closePopup_?

Comment: `Click` on my custom popup

Comment: So inside your custom popup you are closing the popup? Then why do you need a loop on all application forms? Is it not just _this.Close();_?

Comment: yes, it can be done, but it does not solve my problem

Comment: replacing to `Hide();` also does not help

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand what is the wrong behavior. Once you have the 'popup' open, you need to click on it two times to close it? Or after closing the popup you need to click two times on the main form to use it again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141270/discussion-between-styx-and-steve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something else in your code or you make something with the main window that changes the normal behavior of the forms engine. I have tried to build a sample app with LinqPAD using the code above and I have a normal behavior as expected. When I close the popup the focus is restored to the main form.

Nevertheless you could use the main form saved instance in the Tag property to call the Activate method and restore the focus to the main form.

```
public void closePopUp(string formName)
{
    // No need to loop over all application OpenForms if you just want
    // to close this popup
    // for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    // {
    //    string name = Application.OpenForms[i].Name; //for debugging only
    //    if (Application.OpenForms[i].Name == formName)
    //        Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
    //}           

    var mainForm = this.Tag as Form;
    this.Close();
    if(mainForm != null)
        mainForm.Activate();
}
```

Note, I use a cast to the base Form class, so your code doesn't depend on the popup created by a particular class instance. This is possible because Activate is a base class method.